# What is the next number in the integer sequence?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, formation-of-numbers, sequence

What is the next number in the following sequence?

> 25 27 30 34 39 45 52 60 69 79 69 60 52 45 39 34 30 26 22 18
>   82 78 74 70 66 67 64 60 65 80 ?

Comment: Could you please explain the downvotes? Thank you very much. I really want to improve the quality of my questions in the future :)

Comment: You should try to provide at least little bit of context or a small hint, otherwise it forces people to resort to guesswork. I think you should also be more precise with the tags - is this really a **strongly** mathematics oriented puzzle? And do **all** of the other tags apply - they seem somewhat contradictory.

Comment: You may want to read [Number-Sequence Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5712) for some hints on why this is getting downvotes, and for some guidance on how to turn a number-sequence challenge into an interesting puzzle.

Answer (score 5):

Well as a partial, perhaps to help somebody:

> The numbers going up to 79 are +2, +3... +10 and then reversed until 30.

Comment: Yeah, and then it's -4, -4, -4, -4, (reverse and +1), -4, -4, -4, -4, (reverse and +1), and some weird stuff after that. I can't see a repeating pattern throughout the sequence, though.

Comment: @R.M Yeah, I saw that, but it was obvious and really odd and I don’t know what to do with it

Comment: @thecoder16 I really apologize, but could you delete your answer so I can delete my question? It's totally okay if you don't want to.

Comment: @NL628 don’t mind too much, but what was your intended solution? I’m a little curious.

Comment: And tbh it shouldn’t matter that much if the question is deleted or not because I don’t think it’s getting attention anymore